# which part of this code is slowing my program

Tags: java, biginteger

i was answering a contest question using this code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;
//ans is modulu 998244353

public class ShiftAndAdd {
    private static long mod = 998244353;
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BigInteger ans=new BigInteger("0");
        int n,m;
        BigInteger numb_a,numb_b;

        n= input.nextInt();
        m=input.nextInt();
        numb_a=input.nextBigInteger();
        numb_b=input.nextBigInteger();
        long[] a = new long[n];
        long[] b = new long[m];
        long[] a1 = new long[n];//will contain indices of cells of "a" containing 1's
        long[] b1 = new long[m];
        int ka1=0;//will be actual length of a1
        int kb1=0;//will be actual length of b1



        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            a[n-1-i]=numb_a.longValue()%10;
            numb_a=numb_a.divide(new BigInteger("10"));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
            b[m-1-i]=numb_b.longValue()%10;
            numb_b=numb_b.divide(new BigInteger("10"));
        }
        int a1start=(m>=n)?m-n:0;
        ka1=a1start;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(a[i]==1)
                a1[ka1++]=i;
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            if(b[i]==1)
                b1[kb1++]+=++counter;
            else b1[kb1++]=counter;


        //answer:
        for(int i=a1start;i<ka1;i++) {
            ans=ans.add(BigInteger.valueOf((fastExp((long)2,(n-1-a1[i]))%mod *b1[(int)(a1[i]+a1start)] %mod)%mod));
        }
        print(ans.longValue());
    }//end main


    private static long fastExp(long a,long b) {
        if(b>0) {
            if(b%2==0)
                return fastExp((a%mod*a%mod)%mod,b/2);
            else return (a%mod*fastExp(a,b-1)%mod)%mod;
        }
        return 1;
    }//end method fastExp

    private static  void print(long t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }//end method print

}//end class ShiftAndAdd
```

however,the online compiler gave me that time limit exceeded for some input(which inputs very very large integer to variables numb_a and numb_b)
my problem is that i don't know where the time limit has exceeded,was it when i as reading the integers because class BigInteger's methods are slow?or is it because of slow methods valueOf and add of this class?
i need to know the reason to try to fix it

Comment: So try to add logs which will log milliseconds to parts of the code you assume may be slow and step-by-step you'll be able to find the culprit.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do, and in what time? What are the input values expected? Do you really need BigIntegers? They can be pretty slow, but are unavoidable if you need really large numbers.

Comment: Why don't you work with strings instead? ISTM you are counting 1's in both input values, and then do some calculations with that. Instead of repeatedly dividing a large BigInteger by 10, you can much more easily simply count 1's in a string. So don't read input as biginteger, just as string. Only resort to BigIntegers much later on, if necessary.

Comment: The code contains `numb_a.longValue()%10;` -- which means that the original value cannot exceed a `long`  OR the code plays tricks with the value truncation of `longValue()` OR the code gives wrong results for really large values.

Comment: `fastExp(a,b)` is called with a constant `a=2` - so this recursive method can be replaced by a simple bitshift `1L << b`.

Comment: http://codeforces.com/contest/1066/problem/E
i was solving this problem and i don't think it can be solved by other way than using BIgInteger i mean how can i store and manipulate the very large inputted number using something other than biginteger?using string[] array will take same time and more implementation
anyone has another idea to store and manipulate a number with maximum 2*10^5 digits??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have to use java.math.BigInteger it is better to use primitive long instead, using immutable objects is good for scalability but as you are not running more than one thread will not get benefit of using it, but will get drawback of GC, the GC will work more frequent if you used Objects more than using primitives.

Comment: codeforces.com/contest/1066/problem/E i was solving this problem and i don't think it can be solved by other way than using BIgInteger i mean how can i store and manipulate the very large inputted number using something other than biginteger?using string[] array will take same time and more implementation anyone has another idea to store and manipulate a number with maximum 2*10^5 digits??

Comment: is it going to be bigger than primitive long?   The signed long has a minimum value of -(2^63) and a maximum value of (2^63)-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of (2^64)-1

Comment: yes the inputted number is actually a binary number with its most significant digit always 1 and number of digits can be from 1 to 200000
this number of digits can't be stored in a variable of type long

Comment: if you are talking about Binary representation for the value you can use 0b like long bytes = 0b11010010_01101001_10010100_10010010; and to get it back to binary use Long.toBinaryString(long i);